# How can I filter a crosstab query in Access?

Tags: crosstab

Folks,
I have this crosstab query, It shows all the budgets I have in my database, What I need to do its to have a filter so I can just see the Id Budget I choice.
THis is my sql code:

```
Prespuesto=Budget

TRANSFORM Sum(qGrafpv.Importe_CD) AS SumaDeImporte_CD
SELECT qGrafpv.[Id Presupuesto], qGrafpv.[Orden Partida], qGrafpv.[Nombre Partida], Sum(qGrafpv.Importe_CD) AS [Total de Importe_CD]
FROM qGrafpv
GROUP BY qGrafpv.[Id Presupuesto], qGrafpv.[Orden Partida], qGrafpv.[Nombre Partida]
PIVOT Format([MínDeComienzo],"yyyy-mm");
```